# Try and Accept: Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to iterate over several elements that may or may no be there based on the the Imei I input and the result it gives.

There are a few different statuses that come back. Two as IDs and two as Xpaths.

Right now I am stuck on trying to iterate over these elements based off what is visible and not.

When a clean IMEI is submitted, I am able to get the print statement I would like, but when I used a bad IMEI, I only get errors or no output whatsoever. The code doesnt even try to check for the second element. I've written this many ways for the past two weeks and still cannot figure this out. I am finally posting my code here to see if there any any number of ways to write this code out.

https://gist.github.com/Brendyne/c3f857bb2aa180479c36e466a5c7f724

Comment: You need to tell us where exactly the problem occurs, and what are the errors you are getting in some cases.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Brendyne/a7ddf74a3f0bd9afca401c81cbd67f3b

Comment: I am trying to find results of the imei that is submitted.

Comment: From lines 128 and on is where I experience errors. My code is not checking for the 2nd elif if the first if condition isnt there.